# How can I uninstall only one of the versions of Libre Office?

Tags: uninstall, libreoffice, regex, software-uninstall

I have both versions of Libre Office installed - 4.3 and the default:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep libreoffice
```

shows

```
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-help-en-us
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-writer
libreoffice4.3
libreoffice4.3-base
libreoffice4.3-calc
libreoffice4.3-debian-menus
libreoffice4.3-dict-en
libreoffice4.3-dict-es
libreoffice4.3-dict-fr
libreoffice4.3-draw
libreoffice4.3-en-us
libreoffice4.3-impress
libreoffice4.3-math
libreoffice4.3-ure
libreoffice4.3-writer
```

I only want `libreoffice4.3-*` and not `libreoffice^/(?!4.3)-*`

Is there a way of using this sort of regex in the `apt-get` command?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` accepts POSIX regexes (not shell-style wildcards):

```
sudo apt-get remove '^libreoffice4.3-*'
```

will remove

```
libreoffice4.3
libreoffice4.3-base
libreoffice4.3-calc
libreoffice4.3-debian-menus
libreoffice4.3-dict-en
libreoffice4.3-dict-es
libreoffice4.3-dict-fr
libreoffice4.3-draw
libreoffice4.3-en-us
libreoffice4.3-impress
libreoffice4.3-math
libreoffice4.3-ure
libreoffice4.3-writer
```

and those which depend on them. (That's why `apt-get remove libreoffice4*` doesn't do what you think it would.)

So try:

```
sudo apt-get remove '^libreoffice-.*' libreoffice
```

which will remove:

```
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-help-en-us
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-writer
libreoffice
```

From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get):

```
If no package matches the given expression and the expression
contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX
regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the
database. Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that
matching is done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and
'lowest'. If this is undesired, anchor the regular expression with
a '^' or '$' character, or create a more specific regular
expression.
```